# How to work with Aviary SDK in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, aviary

I want to create an image editing app and I am using Aviary but I can't find any tutorials on Aviary, that's why I'm having a problem on working on it.

Are there any tutorials for how to use Aviary SDK for iOS?

I am reading [this document](http://www.aviary.com/ios-documentation), but are there are any tutorials, to easily show what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an Aviary object:

```
AFPhotoEditorController *e = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:IMAGE];

[e setDelegate:self];

[self presentModalViewController:e animated:YES];
```

Then implement Finished & Canceled Delegate methods:

```
- (void)photoEditor:(AFPhotoEditorController *)editor finishedWithImage:(UIImage *)image

- (void)photoEditorCanceled:(AFPhotoEditorController *)editor
```

Good Luck!

Comment: its giving me following warning on set.delegate sending ViewController* to parameter of incompatible tyoe id <AFPhotoEditorControllerDelegate ..what i m doing i m using image picker and selecting that image and passing in to - (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)imageToEdit ..

Comment: thanks mustaga ibrahim .. atleast it opened a new window in which i can edit my picture.. i which there could be more tutorials to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with detailed instructions on how to use the Aviary SDK from the Aviary website:

[Aviary SDK Documentation](http://www.aviary.com/ios-documentation)

I hope this will help you.